# Is it possible to launch a groovy command within powershell?

Tags: powershell, groovy

I am wondering if it's possible to run a groovy command within the powershell console?  Whenever I'm uninstalling or installing my application, I use a bunch of predefined groovy commands to do so on the command line.

ie.) groovy uninstall.groovy -p e:\Software\deploy_script.properties -b batch bundle

I am a bit stuck in terms of how to go about this.  I've created a script that launches the cmd.exe window but I am unsure how to code it next to specifically add the lines "groovy uninstall.groovy -p e:\Software\deploy_script.properties -b batch bundle" so it gets displayed on the cmd prompt.

Start-Process -FilePath "C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe"

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

Comment: Powershell is - just like old CMD - a command line interface. You can run external tools or executables just like in CMD or use cmdlets like [Start-Process](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7) for example.

Comment: I've used Start-Process to launch the cmd line interface, but I would like for the text of "groovy uninstall.groovy -p e:\Software\deploy_script.properties -b batch bundle" to also be entered and initiated once the cmd line interface has been displayed.  Eliminates the need for enter the command in manually

Comment: So you're using one command line interface to start the next command line interface to start a command line tool.  ;-)  You can use Start-Process to start your groovy executable for `-FilePath` paramter and provide the necessary options as the `-ArgumentList` parameter.